Properties of onto transformation matrix
I totally disagree with the following statement given by David Lay in the book Linear algebra and its applications:

If $T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ maps $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto $\mathbb{R}^m$, then its standard matrix $A$ has a pivot in each row (by Theorem 12 and Theorem 4).

I can't imagine the onto transformation using a square matrix with a pivot in each row. From my point of view, for square matrix there should be a row of zeros to have free variables and be onto transformation. So it's impossible to have a pivot in each row in this case.
Could you please explain to me where I'm going wrong?

If $n>m$, how can you think about a square matrix? In the case $m=n$ , there will not be any free variables at all. Perhaps you are not correctly interpreting what it means for $T$ to map onto.

$A$ is meant to have $m$ rows and $n$ columns, so not necessarily be square. One can still do row reduction and talk about pivots.

You can have a free variable for square matrix if you have a full row of zeros, for example.
I re-read the material again, there is no indication that m must not be equal to n. Moreover, in the answers to the problems it is clearly visible that for a one-to-one transformation m >= n, and for m <= n, therefore the equality of m and n is implied.

Sorry mistyping, for one-to-on m >= n, for onto m <= n

If $m$ is meant to be equal to $n$, then the author wouldn't have used two different letters to mean the same thing. You don't write $T:{\bf R}^n\to{\bf R}^m$ if you mean for $m$ and $n$ to be equal.

Understood, Evgen?

I have a Study Guide for this book with answers to the problems, and the answer for this problem is m <= n for onto and m >= n for one-to-one transfomations. Therefore, the author definitely believed that n could be equal to m.

OK. I wrote, $A$ is not necessarily square; you wrote, equality of $m$ and $n$ is implied. I thought you were saying, $m$ and $n$ must be equal, but now I think what you were saying was the possibility of the equality of $m$ and $n$ is implied. So, we agree. The real problem, then, is you write, "I can't imagine the onto transformation using a square matrix with a pivot in each row." But think of $A$ being the identity matrix. It is square, it has a pivot in each row, and it is the matrix of an onto transformation, the transformation $T(v)=v$ for all $v$.

If A is an identity matrix, then the transformation is by definition one-to-one, because with the identity matrix in place you are always map one vector to exactly one vector.

Yes. So, the identity matrix is a square matrix, it doesn't have a row of zeros, it represents an onto transformation, and it has a pivot in each row. Does this example help you to see where you were going wrong? By the way, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to include @Gerry in it.

@Gerry, it doesn't represent onto transformation, it represents one-to-one transformation, because identity matrix map any vector to itself. Onto means that you can map several vectors from R^n to one vector to R^m.

No, Evgen, that's definitely not what "onto" means. "$f:A\to B$ is onto" means for every $b$ in $B$ there is at least one $a$ in $A$ such that $f(a)=b$. In particular, for any set $A$, the map $f:A\to A$ given by $f(a)=a$ for all $a$ in $A$, is certainly onto. Do you have a quote of the definition of "onto" from some source?

@Gerry Ok, my definition is not accurate. Onto means "at least one", one-to-one means "at most one". But how can the identity transforamtion (you spoke above) be "onto"?

How can it not be onto, Evgen? If $f:A\to A$ is given by $f(a)=a$ for all $a$ in $A$, then let $b$ be in $A$; then $f(b)=b$, so there is an element $a$ in $A$ such that $f(a)=b$, namely, $a=b$.

Are you convinced that the identity transformation is onto, Evgen?

NO, I'm not @Gerry

OK, Evgen. Suppose $A={1,2}$, and $f:A\to A$ is given by $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=2$. Do you agree that $f$ is the identity map on $A$, and that $f$  is onto? If not, which part do you disagree with, and why?

Are you still here, Evgen?

@Gerry, sorry for the delay.
I understood the root of the problem, I misunderstood the transformation definitions. In the definition of one-to-one transformation, "at most one" means that there may be no correspondence at all between b in R^m and x in R^n. So if we always have such a correspondence, as in the identity matrix case, then it's onto transformation by definition. Thank you for your patience Gerry.

Quoting from the question,
"I can't imagine the onto transformation using a square matrix with a pivot in each row. From my point of view, for square matrix there should be a row of zeros to have free variables and be onto transformation. So it's impossible to have a pivot in each row in this case.
"Could you please explain to me where I'm going wrong?"
Where you are going wrong is exemplified by the square matrix
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&1\cr}
$$
which (is in reduced row-echelon form and) doesn't have a row of zeros but does represent an onto transformation (from ${\bf R}^2$ to ${\bf R}^2$). The transformation is onto because for every element $v$ in the codomain there is an element $u$ in the domain such that $Au=v$; namely, we can (and must) take $u$ to be $v$.
